# Is it correct that Spring is also used for front-end?

Tags: java, spring, frontend, backend

I am simply looking for some confirmation. I had assumed Spring was only for back-end, yet some features seem to be made for front-end, which confuses me.

Example: [Oauth2Login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.5/reference/html5/#oauth2login)

Is this true? Simply asking this to clear up some confusion.

Comment: You can use it for whatever you want. Authenticate your backend, or writing JavaFX Desktop applications with Spring. You can use Spring basically in every Java Application.

Comment: "The OAuth 2.0 Login feature provides an application with the capability to have users log in to the application " - the Oauth2Login that you linked is for backends to allow users to log in with Oath2

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yeah but it doesn't work well for a REST api, because when you try to access the api, you are redirected to a login page, whereas with a REST api you'd expect it to ask for an auth token and then give you the information right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "for frontend". Spring is a java framework: anything written in java can use it. For example, if you have a desktop application it can be written in all java, and it can use Spring too.

With web applications, you generally need HTML, javascript, CSS and not just java code. Spring can produce HTML [with its own mvc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) or a template engine such as [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) and serve or generate javascript or CSS. For example spring-security can generate login forms and handle them, too. In that sense Spring also has an impact on frontend. However, it is not a "frontend framework" as such, it is a java framework and can be leveraged wherever java is used.

Answer (score 2):

Spring can use additional Frameworks like Thymeleaf, which is used in your example to provide a template HTML page. Since Oauth2 uses re-direct links for successful and unsuccessful authorization, to make a good example without relying on 3rd-Party-URIs to redirect to, your provided OAuth2 example uses Thymeleaf to have a Template to redirect to upon successful authorization.